# Error with fork, execvp in C?

Tags: c, shell, execvp

I'm having trouble with execvp and fork.  When I run the code, exec doesn't work even when the file is created.  It simply returns a "Bad address" error.  Also, the printf("in the child") does not appear when I run it.  How can my code get to execvp without printing "in the child"?

```
     pid = fork();
     switch(pid) {
     case -1:
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR WITH FORK\n");
         exit(1);
         break;

     case 0:
         printf("in the child");
         fd = open(filename,O_CREAT | O_APPEND,0777);
         if(dup2(fd,1) < 0)
         {
             fprintf(stderr,"dup error: %s",strerror(errno));
         }

         if(execvp(command,args) == -1)  //is null terminated
         {
             fprintf(stderr,"exec error %s\n",strerror(errno));
         }

         break;

     default:
        wait(NULL);
        break;
```

Comment: Buffering, flushing, etc. Add a newline.

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about.  The file gets created so the filename string if formatted properly with null.  where would I need a newline that would make my code work?  what buffer are you talking about?

Comment: The buffer in `printf`. Make it print `"in the child\n"` to see the output.

Comment: I see, thanks.  I didn't expect a newline to effect whether or not something printed.  Any idea why i keep getting a bad address?  It works when I take out the redirection stuff, but with it in the code, i get a bad address.

Comment: Did you check that `fd` is valid?

Comment: "Bad address" means your *command* and/or *args* are invalid.

Comment: Yes.  I threw in an message to stderr if open did not work, but it did, and the file gets created.  However, execvp still returns a bad address.  But when I comment out the open and dup2 stuff, execvp runs and then I end in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The array of pointers (the second argument in `execvp()`) must be terminated by a `NULL` pointer. Append a `0` or `NULL` at the end of `args`.